# RequireJS tries to load webpack externals

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

Using Webpack, I'm exporting two distribution files for a project. One with dependencies bundled and one without.

Throughout the application, we use commonjs `require('lodash.assign');` includes which webpack understands.

However, I've configured one of our builds to ignore these (for users who already use lodash and have it available).

```
externals = {
    'lodash.assign': 'var _.assign',
    'lodash.clonedeep': 'var _.cloneDeep'
};
```

This works as expected. However, because our `libraryTarget` is `umd` we support RequireJS. However, RequireJS still actually thinks these files should be loaded and I'm seeing a ton of errors:

```
require.min.js:1 GET http://127.0.0.1/_.assign.js req.load
@ Uncaught Error: Script error for "_.assign"
```

It can't figure out where to find script. How can I configure webpack, or even requirejs to ignore these, since they're being mapped by webpack?

By looking at the compiled output, I see the reason requirejs thinks it's supposed to load these files:

```
define(["_.assign", "_.cloneDeep"], factory);
```

When I manually modify code to the following, it works:

```
define(['lodash'], factory);
```